# python api of google adwords(googleads) is giving "INVALID_CONVERSION_TYPE" when calling the OfflineConversionAdjustmentFeed operation

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using googleads API  to perform the following operations:
- (1) upload new conversions
- (2) adjust uploaded conversions
The first operation  could be done successfuly.
However the second opeartion which is the adjustment of the uploaded conversion is giving the error "INVALID_CONVERSION_TYPE".

According to the documentation in https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/OfflineConversionFeedService.OfflineConversionError#reason.
The reason for this error is that the conversion name does not match any uploaded conversion for the same customer, 
although i have uploaded the conversion with the same conversion name for the same customer.

I am posting my request and the response i am receiving:

```
 request=[{
    'operator': 'ADD',
    'operand':
        {
            'adjustmentTime': '20190802 235959 Etc/GMT',
            'googleClickId': 'gcliID',
            'adjustedValueCurrencyCode': 'EUR',
            'conversionName': 'YY',
            'adjustedValue': xx,
            'xsi_type': 'GclidOfflineConversionAdjustmentFeed',
            'conversionTime': '20190731 235959 Etc/GMT',
            'adjustmentType': 'RESTATE'
        }
}
]
```

```
response = {
    'ListReturnValue.Type': 'OfflineConversionAdjustmentFeedReturnValue',
    'value': [
        {
            'conversionName': None,
            'adjustmentTime': None,
            'adjustmentType': None,
            'adjustedValue': None,
            'adjustedValueCurrencyCode': None,
            'OfflineConversionAdjustmentFeed.Type': 'GclidOfflineConversionAdjustmentFeed',
            'googleClickId': None,
            'conversionTime': None
        }
    ],
    'partialFailureErrors': [
        {
            'fieldPath': 'operations[0].operand.conversionName',
            'fieldPathElements': [
                {
                    'field': 'operations',
                    'index': 0L
                },
                {
                    'field': 'operand',
                    'index': None
                },
                {
                    'field': 'conversionName',
                    'index': None
                }
            ],
            'trigger': None,
            'errorString': 'OfflineConversionAdjustmentError.INVALID_CONVERSION_TYPE',
            'ApiError.Type': 'OfflineConversionAdjustmentError',
            'reason': 'INVALID_CONVERSION_TYPE'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever solved this issue? I'm having the very same one. The only solution I could find is not to use gclid, but switched to orderId - now adjustment works for me.